# Is there a better way to model an ellipse with 2 circular cuts?

Tags: modeling, topology

I am trying to model an ellipse with two circular cuts inside :

[image: Ellipse with 2 circular cuts]

After some planning, I came up with the following topology :

[image: Ellipse topology]

While technically all quads, the large ones in the middle are almost triangles and really stand out in terms of scale. Since this is a flat surface, the subdivision modifier still looks nice, but I really wonder if there is a better way of doing this.

EDIT : here's the full model for clarity :

[image: Ellipse 3D model]

Comment: If this is a flat surface you could use a ngon, also, if you use a Subdivision Surface modifier you could use less vertices for your holes, like 8

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. It's definitely a flat surface, but I plan to extrude it to give it some thickness. I tried doing that with an N-gon & 8 vertices for the holes, but the subdivision modifier makes a huge mess of the N-gon unfortunately

Comment: maybe show an image of the final object you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I edited the question and added a picture. It really looks nice, but I'm beginning with Blender and am really trying to do things the right way.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a *Subdivision Surface* modifier, you don't need so many vertices, you can use 8 vertex holes, and also an ngon like that should work:

[image]

Comment: Hmm this doesn't seem to work for me, I get a lot of pinching after subdividing. Thank you for your help though, I guess I'll just watch your videos to get better at modelling!

Comment: you may need to inset the ngon, could you please share your file?

Comment: I just deleted it, I'll move on to another exercise